# Is there another way to embed the recipient view in app with URL which has much longer valid time?

Tags: docusignapi

From the official doc:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/
Returns a URL that enables you to embed the recipient view of the DocuSign UI in your applications.

The URL is time-limited
The URL returned by this method is valid for one use, and you must use or display it within a couple of minutes after it is generated. After the recipient is redirected to the recipient view, they must interact with the DocuSign system periodically or their session will time out.

I am trying to make a envelope and get a URL embed the recipient view in my app? But from the doc, EnvelopeViews:createRecipient would only a URL which have a couple minutes lifetime.
I want the URL to be valid for much longer time. I want to store URL in DB for future use.
It would be better that I can configure expiration date.
Is there another way for DocuSign API which can meet my need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, these restrictions you mention are security related. And are there to ensure that the URL is not accidently exposed to the wrong person. This is just one of many defense mechanisms making DocuSign super secure.

The best thing to do is generate the URL only when your user is ready to sign. Storing it in DB is not good practice for many reasons. You can store **envelopeId** in your DB and make the API call only when needed to generate the URL.

For more details please find article on this exact topic:

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/long-lived-embedded-signing-urls